# Where does Collabnet Subversion store its user database?

Tags: user-accounts, svn

I'm trying to migrate subversion from an old server to a new one. I can copy all the repository information, but I'm stuck when it comes to the users. Do I have to recreate all the users manually or can I copy a "Users database"?

Answer (score 1):

Where the users are stored is dependent on the way the repository is served. If it is served via SSH then svnserve uses the system users. If it is served via svnserve plain daemon then they're stored in the svnserve configuration files. If it is served via http/https then they're in the Apache configuration file. Where these files are is explained in the chapter 6 of the SVN book you can find [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)